# Custom functions DataType to make text in cell bold office.js

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-web-addins

Are there any ways to make the text bold without using the Excel.run method in a custom function?

I found how to format the numbers, but I could not find the formatting of the strings
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/custom-functions-data-types-concepts

Comment: What do you mean `without using the Excel.run method in a custom function`. My functions take `context` as a param for example, is that what you mean?

Comment: I use this to format my `rng` --> `XL_Formatting.Do_Format_Rng_Blue_White_Bold = async function Do_Format_Rng_Blue_White_Bold(context, rng) {
    rng.format.fill.color = Formats_Obj.fill.color.blue
    rng.format.font.color = Formats_Obj.font.color.white
    rng.format.font.bold = Formats_Obj.font.bold
    return context;
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to set the text to bold etc using the formatted number value data type. You can however call the Excel API and set the formatting on the cell that called the custom function. Access to the Excel API from a custom function require the use of the shared runtime.

The ability to apply additional formatting to formatted number value data types is a great feature request. Consider posting this as an item for the backlog in the [Microsoft 365 Developer Community](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform).